# Is it possible to use the Goode Homolosine projection in QGIS?

Tags: qgis, coordinate-system, grass-gis, homolosine

Is it possible to use the Goode Homolosine projection in QGIS? Both QGIS and GRASS seem to have trouble with the interruptions, squashing the higher latitudes together. I tried +proj=goode +ellps=sphere +datum=wgs84 as a custom CRS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There has been a question on interrupted projections before: [Discontinuous or Interrupted map projections?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/1775/discontinous-or-interrupted-map-projections)

The conclusion was that proj4 (which is used for projection handling in QGIS and GRASS) does not support interrupted projections.

Comment: I should have mentioned a ticket on the Proj.4 tracker for Goode Homolosine support (which was created after that question was asked): http://trac.osgeo.org/proj/ticket/106. Looks like I don't have as new a proj as I thought, though; I'll try updating my proj and see how it goes. Sorry for the duplicate question.

Comment: All projections are interrupted... i.e. the counter domain is a finite space, not infinite ;)

Answer (score 7):

With QGIS Lisboa, there is now a basic support for Goode Homolosine projection.

I downloaded IGH data from http://edc2.usgs.gov/glcc/fao/data_specifications.php

and set up this user CRS:

```
+proj=goode +lon_0=-100 +x_0=-11119487.43 +y_0=0 +a=6370997 +b=6370997 +towgs84=0,0,0,0,0,0,0 +units=m +no_defs
```

for North America.

lon_0 and x_0 are from Appendix 03 of this document: http://proceedings.esri.com/library/userconf/proc98/proceed/TO850/PAP844/P844.HTM

Overlaying natural Earth world boundaries_m, I get this picture:

[image]

Fitting good in North America (about 20km misplaced), and distorted in other regions.

---

**EDIT**

Just noticed that proj knows interrupted goode homolosine by now:

```
+proj=igh +ellps=sphere +towgs84=0,0,0 +lon_0=100w +x_0=-11119487.43
```

gives me this picture of Natural Earths world boundaries and a 10-degree-vector grid:

[image]

I'm not sure which parameteres apart from `+proj=igh` are necessary anymore.

Comment: Using the definition above I get a pixel shift. For me the definition `+proj=igh +towgs84=0,0,0` worked just fine

Answer (score 6):

QGIS 2.18 is nigh on fully supporting the Homolosine for rasters. You just need to be aware of [issue #959](https://github.com/OSGeo/gdal/issues/959): perform any raster warpping directly with GDAL using the `CHECK_WITH_INVERT_PROJ` parameters and you are good.

Regarding vectors things are still complex. Some of the errors AndreJ [shows in his answer](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/67122/21532) prevail. The cause is simple: QGis is not aware that it is a Cartographic programme and considers the co-domain of any projection to be an infinite space.

This has a simple fix: intersect any vector layer imported into QGis with the Homolosine co-domain. Some time back I made available [a discrete co-domain vector](https://zenodo.org/record/1841337) defined at intervals of one degree longitude and latitude.

[image: DOI]

[image]

Comment: Thank you! It works perfectly!