# How to create an interrupted Mollweide map in R?

Tags: coordinate-system, r

I am wondering if it is possible to create an interrupted Mollweide map in R.

This question is similar to [Discontinuous or Interrupted map projections?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/q/1775/35320) which does not really have a satisfactory answer for my purposes.

I know you can use the Interrupted Goode Homolosine and other interrupted projections are available via alternate open-source tools such as GMT.  However, I do not know how to use GMT and would prefer to avoid learning another software tool just for this purpose.  I've also seen that the M_Map toolbox in Matlab has support for the interrupted Mollweide, but I do not have access to Matlab.

Is this possible in R or alternatively in ArcGIS?

An example of what I'm looking for:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

R projects `sp` objects using proj4 strings. After some googleing, I got the impression that interrupted projections are not easily accomplished via proj4 arguments. Sounds like the `mapproj` package doesn't support interrupted projections either. I bet there is a solution, but probably not an easy one (e.g. check out this R-sig-Geo answer: https://stat.ethz.ch/pipermail/r-sig-geo/2007-April/001980.html)

Comment: Actually, the Goode Homolosine projection can be achieved via CRS `+proj=igh`, and the resulting shape cropped by the CounterDomain.geojson available [here](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/309395).