# What projection appeared in the NYTimes this morning?

Tags: coordinate-system

[image]

Perhaps not as GIS related as some, but definitely about maps.
Can anyone identify the [map projection that appeared in the New York Times this morning?](http://www.nytimes.com/interactive/2011/12/06/science/1206-world.html) It's not one I've seen before, and a quick scan through [*Map Projections: A Working Manual*](http://pubs.er.usgs.gov/publication/pp1395) did not yield the result I was looking for.

Comment: There's a little bit of discussion on the Cahill-Keyes projection at http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/1775/discontinous-or-interrupted-map-projections

Comment: [Obligatory XKCD comic that lists a whole lot of these](http://xkcd.com/977/)

Answer (score 30, accepted):

[image]

It appears to be the Cahill-Keyes modified version of the Waterman Butterfly projection (see the Gene Keyes source at the bottom of the image).  More info:
http://www.genekeyes.com/  and here:  http://www.cartotalk.com/index.php?showtopic=7360

Comment: Yes, it reminded me of the butterfly but not quite.

Answer (score 23):

More precisely, Cahill-Keyes is a modified version of [B.J.S. Cahill's 1909 Butterfly World Map](http://www.genekeyes.com/B.J.S._CAHILL_RESOURCE.html). Mine was first devised in 1975, with early hand-drawn b&w prototypes printed in 1979-84. The [Beta-1 digital version](http://www.genekeyes.com/MEGAMAP-BETA-1/Megamap-Beta-1.html) appeared this year. Steve Waterman independently designed an octahedral Cahill-like map on different precepts than mine in 1996, and has published wall-size versions in color; see my [friendly detailed critique of the Waterman Map](http://www.genekeyes.com/WATERMAN-REVIEW/Waterman-review.html).