# What projection is this and how to use it in a GIS?

Tags: qgis, arcgis-desktop, coordinate-system, open-source-gis, manifold

I have a request to do a map in non-standard projection:
[image: non-standar projection]

(source: http://www4.agr.gc.ca/AAFC-AAC/display-afficher.do?id=1263246127905&lang=eng)
I couldn't manage to find it my materials. As well I wasn't able to apply such projection in ArcGIS.
Do you know what projection is it? And how to apply it in ArcGIS or Manifold or any open source GIS?

Comment: On a related note: http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/1775/discontinous-or-interrupted-map-projections

Comment: Perhaps you could persuade your client to use a better projection--almost any projection centered around the southern Pacific ocean would be more accurate and revealing than this one!

Comment: I've managed to find and contact the author. It appeared that it's his own devise. So it rather will not be possible to reproduce it with standard tools.

Answer (score 3):

I guess it is something like this kind of interupted projection: http://www.progonos.com/furuti/MapProj/Normal/ProjInt/ProjIntA/projIntA.html#KHComposite but I don't think you can do that eaysily with GIS software.